# PHP Server ошибка: "The requested resource / was not found on this server."

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code

При запуске данного кода в VS Code через PHP Server, который успешно запускался и работал на видео, по которому я учусь, в браузере открывается страница фото которой прикреплено ниже. Когда я нажимаю на "Отправить", браузер выбрасывает мне ошибку "The requested resource / was not found on this server."

Я попытался найти решение в интернете и, увы, ничего не нашёл. Помогите пожалуйста устранить эту ошибку.

```
<?php print_r($_GET);?>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    
  <form action="/" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить"/>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Относительно части когда - всё работает корректно. 
Непонятно, какое конкретно видео Вы смотрите, но:

1. У Вас есть форма:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="/" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить"/>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

В этой форме в теге `<form action="/" method="POST">` В поле `action` - как Вы, наверное, уже догадались действие. Вам надо передать куда-то введённые данные поля Имени. 
Передать Вы его можете, к примеру, в другой файл php, указав в `action` путь к файлу относительно текущей директории. 
К примеру, если у меня файл, который должен получать значения из формы, лежит в той же директории, то выглядеть это будет так:
`<form action="newFile.php" method="POST">`

2. В форме Вы указываете метод отправки данных - `<form action="/" method="POST">` (В данном случае POST). 
   Однако в начале вы выводите `print_r($_GET);`
   Если Вы хотите выводить введённые данные из формы, то Вам необходимо отображать `$_POST`.
3. В текущей же реализации, Ваша система ругается на то, что в папке нет такого ресурса с именем `/`.
   The requested resource / was not found on this server
   Если Вы хотите, чтобы ресурс обращался сам на себя - используйте `#` вместо `/`.
   Пример:
   `<form action="#" method="POST">`

Вам необходимо не только смотреть видео и повторять, но и пытаться понять то, что Вы повторяете, каждую его часть. 
Больше про формы можете почитать [Тут](https://htmlacademy.ru/tutorial/php/forms)

Comment: Попробовал исправить как вы сказали. Всё заработало! Ошибку понял. Огромное вам спасибо!